Google Cloud Vision API giving occasional but persistent error response to WEB_DETECTION requests after Dec 5 2023 update
We have a C# service that relies heavily on this API to find other locations on the web any given image may already exist. It has been running reliably in production for ~3-4 years, but has started failing intermittently since around March 19, 2024, which I think is when the updates announced 5 Dec 2023 by Google took effect.
I can currently simulate the problem using this handy Google documentation page:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-web
If I configure the request to run a WEB_DETECTION on the image down below using this body:
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "WEB_DETECTION"
        }
      ],
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "https://i.sstatic.net/A8aV6.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

I get an error response:
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 3,
        "message": "Internal processing error: invalid_argument."
      }
    }
  ]
}

Most (approx 86% of our requests) succeed. As far as I can tell, our image is OK but Google is tripping over something when processing the request.

UPDATE 8 May 2024
Original problem image now being successfully processed when tested today. However many still failing, such as:

UPDATE 11 Nov 2024
An update on this issue. I've been reviewing the error rate for the requests of the same type from our system and it's gradually gone down month by month.
         Checks  Errors  Error percent
2024-Oct   4673       1          0.02%
2024-Sep   4161       2          0.05%
2024-Aug   4223       7          0.17%
2024-Jul   4202       6          0.14%
2024-Jun   3766      15          0.40%
2024-May   4175      69          1.65%

Having the error rate down at 0.02% now is probably low enough for us to live with. Interestingly though, most of the recent failing images still contain some form of text.

We're in the exact same boat! What were the "updates announced 5 Dec 2023 by Google"? I may have missed those... Found it: "Improved models are now available" -- 90 days and they became the default, legacy available for 90 further days.

Glad we're not the only ones! I found this announcement from last year:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/release-notes
A few people have reported other problems with Cloud Vision on their issue tracker:https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:187174&s=created_time:desc

We have used the service for many months, but on Wednesday before Easter suddenly we started getting a lot of these errors. Consistently on the same images. Wondering what changed.

We started seeing the errors on March 27th, but we switched the model to builtin/legacy about an hour ago and have not seen errors since then so I guess we have 90 days grace and hope they fix the new model by then...

Six hours later and still no errors from builtin/legacy so that looks like a good option for the time being to workaround this.

This issue is being handled by the engineering team in the pit issue ,  You can vote for this issue by clicking +1 and STAR mark to receive updates on it and for faster resolution you can create a support ticket by clicking here .
